# is this code safe from hacking?? or hacker can manipulate it and gain access to admin privileges?

Tags: ajax, web, admin, server

```
    function submit_login()
{
    $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "index.php",
          data: "username="+$("#username").val()+"&password="+$("#password").val()+(( $("#remember:checked").val() !== undefined ) ? "&remember=1" : ''),
          success: function(data){
             if (data){
                window.location.reload(true);
             }else{
                $('.error').effect('pulsate',100);
               /* $('#username, #password').animate({
                                    backgroundColor: "#aa0000",
                                    color: "#fff"
                                }, 1000 ); */
            }
     }
    });
}
```

Comment: here is the full code

Comment: Stackoverflow is programming community. Please go to Codereview.

Comment: Nothing is safe from hacking.

Comment: then how can i do it?

Comment: function submit_login()
{
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "index.php",
    data: "username="+$("#username").val()+"&password="+$("#password").val()+(( $("#remember:checked").val() !== undefined ) ? "&remember=1" : ''),
    success: function(data){
    if (data){
     window.location.reload(true);
    }else{
      $('.error').effect('pulsate',100);
      /* $('#username, #password').animate({
            backgroundColor: "#aa0000",
            color: "#fff"
           }, 1000 ); */
   }
  }
 });
}

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
 
  //ajaxloader animation
  //start
  $("#loading").ajaxStart(function(){
     $(this).show();
   });
   //stop
  $("#loading").ajaxStop(function(){
     $(this).hide();
   }); 
  
  $("#login").button();
  
  $('#username, #password').focus(function() {
   
   $('.error').fadeOut('slow');
   /*$('#username, #password').animate({
        backgroundColor: "#fff",
        color: "#000"
       }, 1000 ); */
  });
  
 });

Comment: Your post has an [edit] link. Use that instead of adding comments with code. Please take the [tour] before you continue and have a bad experience here.

Answer (score -2):

Not safe.  Should use https//:

The username and password is transmitted in the clear.  A simple IP sniffer can read it.  Especially when the labels are username and password. Too easy.

You do realize this is the reason HTTPS exists.

There are hacker that have sniffers connected to the Internet Backbone and setup a very simple to use IP sniffer that watches the IP traffic and the sniffer looks for the word "password" and it captures the packets for that IP address.

In a corporate environment it is very common for someone to sniff the IP packet on the corporate LAN. Many email clients send the user name and password just like you do.  And it is available to anyone that cares to look.

IP Sniffer software has about a 5-10 minute learning curve and requires no technical knowledge.

Here is a typical scenario.  Some one submits their user name and password to you.  You pass it via AJAX, which is no different then submitting a form from a Browser window, someone captures the IP packets.  And this person that gets their password sniffed from your AJAX request is an idiot that uses the same user name and password for their bank account.

The hacker drains the account, gets caught, and rats you out for being the stupid one that passed the user name and password in the clear (your IP address is in the IP packet as well) . The crook is not going to pay it.  Who is legally responsible for the money stolen from the bank account?

You more than the crook.  It is stupid programmers that give the crook the opportunity and are more to blame than the crook.  There is a huge multi-billion dollar industry just because of stupid programmers that send passwords in the clear.

At least you are helping the economy.

Comment: what possible way can hacker use ? to attack the website

Comment: Your TLS detecting crystal ball is amazing.